# Order Directory.GetAccessControl.GetAccessRules alphabetically

Tags: c#

I have the following code to get the folder permissions for a shared drive:

```
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(directory);

foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in dSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Account:{0} ({1}", rule.IdentityReference.Value,
    rule.FileSystemRights.ToString() + ")");
}
```

I'm running it on two different shared drives that are supposed to be identical to compare the results but the output files are out of order and hard to compare.

How can I sort the results alphabetically?

Comment: "Alphabetically", as in in what sense? The file names? The drive names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `OrderBy` and order by the `IdentityReference.Value`  as that seems to be what you are displaying to the screen. However first you need to cast the collection.

```
var orderedResults = dSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount))
                              .Cast<FileSystemAccessRule>()
                              .OrderBy(rule => rule.IdentityReference.Value);
```

Then in your `foreach` loop just loop on `orderedResults`:

```
foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in orderedResults)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the output of your foreach to a list via Linq or add to a list then order by descending. I actually use the below to return an ordered list of DIR found on a share.

ObjRef.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Name).ToList()